# Loop over Object attributes with except attributes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I can get object attributes with:

```
Class Object
 field :name
 field :email
 field :second_name
end
```

With this loop:

```
<% @object.attributes.each do |attr_name| %>
....
<% end %>
```

If i have 3 attributes I get 3 attributes.

I want only get `attr_name` of `name` and `email` attributes

**How can I in this loop discard or exclude the `field :second_name`**

Thank you

Comment: Blacklist: `(@object.attributes - [:second_name]).each{ ... }` Whitelist: `[:name, :email].each{ ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a condition inside your loop like so:

```
@object.attributes.each do |attr_name|
  unless attr_name.eql?('second_name')
    # Do stuff here
  end
end
```

Comment: Personally, I like `next if attr_name == 'second_name'`, which is functionally the same, but spares you indenting the rest of the method.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what your criteria is for including or excluding particular attributes.

**If you want a Blacklist:**

```
(@object.attributes - [:second_name]).each{ ... }
# Alternatively:
@object.attributes.reject{ |n| n==:second_name }.each{ ... }
```

**If you want a Whitelist:**

```
(@object.attributes & [:name, :email, :socks]).each{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Blacklist:

```
exclude = [:a, :b, :c]
@object.attributes.reject { |k,v| only.include?(k.to_sym) }
```

Whitelist:

```
only = [:a, :b, :c]
@object.attributes.select { |k,v| only.include?(k.to_sym) }
```